# Finding entropy of Nitrogen at low pressures

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, gas

I'm trying to calculate the entropy of gaseous Nitrogen (assumed to be ideal) at a particular state in a thermodynamic cycle. I know the pressure, temperature, and specific volume, but all property tables I've looked at don't extend to the kind of low pressures I'm dealing with. Specifically, the property values I'm dealing with are:

$P = 0.676 \ kPa, \ v=131.8 \ m^3/kg, \ T=300K$

How can I find (or at least estimate) the entropy of my working fluid at this state? Either analytic equations or property table resources would be helpful. Most of the property tables I've looked at only go down to about 10 kPa or so, which makes any sort of interpolation slightly out of the range of the table difficult.

Comment: Give a value at a state that you know, and then I'll tell you how to get it at your pressure.

Comment: The state in question undergoes an isothermal heat rejection process within a piston-cylinder device, and the resulting entropy is 8.019 kJ/kg-K. But other than the temperature and entropy (and that it's still a gas), I don't know anything else about this next state.

Comment: I need to know an entropy value and pressure and temperature at some state, and a pressure and temperature for the state you are interested in.

Comment: You could try the Sackur-Tetrode equation for that.

Comment: Do you know the equation for the effect of pressure on entropy for an ideal gas?

Comment: Yes, that's part of why I need the entropy at this state, because once I know it, I have enough information to find the pressure at another state, which will allow me to find the rest of the property values at the states in the cycle. I was hoping there existed some sort of empirical data or empirical equation for the entropy at low pressure, since I have enough information to (theoretically) compute it at the given state.

Comment: Usually, entropy is expressed relative to a reference state.  Why do you need to know the absolute entropy?